# iOS NetworkExtension: NEAppProxyUDPFlow readDatagram. How to send some extra attributes with datagram?

Tags: ios, networkextension

I want to manipulate data in UDP flow using:

```
udpFlow.readDatagrams { (datagrams, endPoints, error) in
    
    datagrams?.enumerated().forEach({ (args) in
        let (offset, datagram) = args
        let datagramString = String(data: datagram, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        NSLog("datagramString \(String(describing: datagramString)) at offset \(offset)")
        NSLog("Datagram remote endpoints = %@", endPoints?[offset] ?? "Endpoint not found for index = \(offset)")
    })
    guard let udpData = datagrams, let endPoint = endPoints else { return }
    udpFlow.writeDatagrams(udpData, sentBy: endPoint) { (writeError) in
        if let error = writeError {
            NSLog("DataGram write error = %@", error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

How to send more info along with UDP datagram.